# Connect SQL database with PowerShell and retrieve specific information for an group of users that are stored in variable in PowerShell in CN format

Tags: sql, powershell, active-directory

I have a script in SQL that returns a bunch of properties in a database using some queries. Among those properties, the `PRIMARYOWNER` column stores the names of the users in CN format. Like this:

```
CN=BECALI Gigi (SALES-EXT),OU=Users_CARE,OU=SALES,OU=SALEs,DC=net1,DC=cec,DC=com,DC=int
```

They are connected to other columns which stores in the same SQL database  table other information that I want to be retrieved like `DISPLAYNAME, LOGINNAME, OSTYPE, SUITENAME, PUBLISHER, VERSION`.

I want to be able to retrieve the software that is installed on specific machines depending on the Department they are from. I am doing this by retrieving the Departments from Active Directory using the following script and storing the results in a variable.

```
    Clear-Host 
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory
    Write-Host "Processing" 
    $departments = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Property Department |
                   Where-Object { $_.Department } |
                   Select -Expand Department -Unique
```

How do I connect the results from the PowerShell in the CN format with the SQL tables in order to retrieve what software is installed on the specific user in the desired department?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are many ways to achieving this but personally my first guess would be to wrap the powershell in a bit of .NET (VB or C#) as you can call powershell from .NET.

You can then take a look at CLR packages which can be called from SQL server.  This does assume you have access to Visual Studio however.  There may be a better way to do it but this would be my first approach.